# Will or would when making a predictiction

Tags: will-would

When we're making a prediction, I think both "will" or "would" are interchangeable. Is there a difference between them both when it comes to making a prediction? I'm confused because both will and would are talking about a possibility. So the choice is difficult. My understanding about "will" is that a win for United is seen as a real possibility and that "would" is seen as unreal possibility (hypothetitcal).

> *Good afternoon and welcome to Sports Mole's live commentary of the Premier League encounter between Wolverhampton Wanderers and Manchester United. The clash is crucial at both ends of the table, with Wolves currently sitting in the bottom three, while victory for United **will**/**would** move Sir Alex Ferguson's side four points clear of Manchester City at the summit.*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between "will" and "would" for predictions](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/191806/difference-between-will-and-would-for-predictions)

Comment: Yes. _Will_ assumes that United will win, _would_ speaks of '_if_ they win'.

Comment: @KateBunting But how do we know any degree of the certainty into the win. This is talked before the game, so we don't know for sure the final result.

Comment: So, _would_ is the most appropriate choice!

Comment: But both are correct in this context?

Comment: As I said, you could use _will_ if you were super-confident of the result!

Comment: Yes, that's right. But without context, it would be difficult for me how I see the situation. As I have said, this is said before the game kicks off. If the game is going on and the side go 3-0 up in the 89 minutes, and I think the opossing team are diffiucult to score. I would then say "a win for United **will** put them ...."

Answer (score 0):

This is not a prediction:

> The clash is crucial at both ends of the table, with Wolves currently sitting in the bottom three, while victory for United will move Sir Alex Ferguson's side four points clear of Manchester City at the summit.

It states what the effect of a victory for United will be; *implicit* in the utterance is the notion "should that happen".

Here, the notion of "should that happen" is made explicit:

> The clash is crucial at both ends of the table, with Wolves currently sitting in the bottom three, while victory for United would move Sir Alex Ferguson's side four points clear of Manchester City at the summit.

When speaking of the future using **will** in such a context, no reasonable person would assume you're predicting the future, as the semantic focus of the utterance is on the implications of victory for United in terms of league standings.

P.S. A speaker might say "**a**  victory will" to make it even clearer that it's not a prediction.

Comment: So how does "would" work in that sentence? Is "will" wrong there?

Comment: Let's say that a team needs only one more victory to win the league championship title.  One could say "With one more victory they will win the title."  That is not predicting a win but is emphasizing the result that a win would *guarantee*. That a victory is not a present reality or guaranteed to happen is  *implicit* in the sentence. One could also say  "With one more victory they would win the title." That is not predicting a win either. The verb **would**  *explicitly* acknowledges that it is not a present reality and is only a future possibility.

Comment: Both of those sentences are idiomatic. The difference is one of emphasis.

Comment: *A victory will make them the champions.*  The indefinite article means that it is not a prediction, whereas the definite article makes it a prediction:  *The victory will make them the champions*.

Comment: I'm really confused. In short, "would" is used for a hypothetical situation and "will" is used as a real possibility. Is it right in this case?

Comment: @Nyambek  Both *will* and *would* can be used of real possibilities ("A win tomorrow  will|would guarantee our team a place in the quarterfinals") and both can be used in hypothetical situations too: *Imagine a hot air balloon with a gondola made of lead. Would|will that balloon be able to rise into the sky? No, it will|would stay on the ground!*  The difference is one of emphasis; it's not that one is "correct" and the other is "incorrect".  **will** emphasizes the factual (lead is very heavy) and **would** emphasizes the counterfactual (there is no such balloon).

Comment: The language is subtler and more expressive than the picture presented in books whose aim is to teach the basics, and whose chapters end with tests with a "right" answer and a "wrong" answer.

Comment: So in this case, "will" is better because the situation is real, isn't it? Before the match no one knows who will definitely win. However "would" is also possible in that sentence because we're talking about a hypothetical situation. This makes me puzzled because when imagining a situation, I usually use "would".

Comment: @Nyambek: If you want to emphasize that it is merely possible, use **would**. If you want to emphasize the *implications* if the possibility should turn out to be the actuality, you can use "will", but there's no obligation to do so, and emphasis can be made in other ways. The verb is only one of the players on the team, so to speak.