# Why is "would" used in "have to"

Tags: usage, would

Why does speaker B add "would" in his response? Here is a dialogue.

> A: Is it correct to say, "It would be appreciate if you can do something"?
>
> B: For me, it **would** have to be, "I would appreciate it if you could do something".

Comment: Do any of these answer your question: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/343263/will-or-would-when-making-a-predictiction, https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/343478/what-is-the-use-of-would-in-this-context, https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/343243/whats-the-meaning-of-would-in-this-sentence ???

Comment: *It would be **appreciated** if...* OR *I would **appreciate** it if...* The first (passive) version uses the *Past Participle*.

Answer (score 1):

There is an unspoken clause here. I've added it for clarity.

> A: Is it correct to say "X"?
> B: For me, **if I were to say it**, it would have to be "Y".

The "would" is referring to the conditional future in which the speaker B is using the phrase you asked about.

Comment: @Christion Legge. There is no conditional in that sentence. The speaker only uses "would" directly. Why use the past of "would" instead of "will"? The question isn't in the past.

Comment: The conditional is **implied** - unspoken, as Christian says.

Comment: @KateBunting Well, could you explain what the difference between the following is? I will appreciate it if you can help me with my homework. I would appreciate it if you could help me with my homework.

Comment: "I will appreciate it" means "I will be glad of it at some time in the future", and it is not a natural thing for an English speaker to say.  We use the conditional to be polite, by not taking it for granted that the other person will help. The use of _would_ as in your original example was recently discussed [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/343478/what-is-the-use-of-would-in-this-context).

Comment: @KateBunting I'm still unclear. Both are conditional. When I would like to say to someone. What should I choose "I will appreciate it if..." or "I would appreciate it if...?" Where does the difference lie?

Comment: As I said, "I will appreciate it" is not idiomatic English, "I would appreciate it" is.

Comment: @KateBunting So the speaker is considering what would happen if the other person helped them with their homework. That's why "would " works. Using "will" is going to happen, doesn't it?

Comment: Have you read the links to similar questions provided by gotube? It's considered polite to treat the other person's willingness to help as hypothetical rather than certain.

Comment: @Mbutt: The reason native speakers don't like *I **will** appreciate it [if you help me]* is because - as Kate says - it strongly implies you're sure the other person ***will*** help. Which could sound incredibly rude, since that format sometimes *is* used by people in power giving *orders* to underlings. Compare *I **will thank** you not to disturb me* (always an imperious, rude *command*) and *I **would ask** you not to disturb me* (usually a deferential, polite *request*).

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'm beginning to understand. But how can I know the other person will help. Could you illustrate how the scenario is?

Comment: That's not the point! You *can't* "know the other person will help", and it's generally considered rude / presumptuous / disrespectful to use words implying that they definitely *will* help. All you need to know is that *for generations*, native Anglophones have been using circumlocution and "indirect, hesitant, speculative, conditional" phrasing to make  deferential, polite requests. So the preferred format when making a polite request is to refer to what ***would*** happen IF (their choice) the other person helps, not what ***will*** happen WHEN (your prediction / expectation) they help.